# Python cv2.matchTemplate не находит фрагмент изображения

Tags: python, opencv

Всем доброго времени суток.
Использую метод cv2.matchTemplate для поиска фрагмента но он возвращает совсем рандомные координаты. Пробывал добавлять маски, и и разные методы поиска, но результата нету.
Так же в качестве шаблона использовал картинку которой нету на оригинальной картинке, и тем не менее cv2.matchTemplate ее там находил.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv2.imread('./hands-crop.png')

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('./card-10.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

w, h, cc = template.shape

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

threshold = 0.80
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
axarr[0].imshow(img_rgb)
axarr[1].imshow(template)

plt.show()
```

[image: Template 1]
[image: Template 2]
[image: Template 3]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в непонимании и неправильных данных. Возьмем тройку. Размер шаблона не совпадает с размером той же тройки на изображении. Примерно 100x75 против 224x162. Результат не удивителен, ведь matchtemplate сюрфит шаблоном по изображению и дает самый подходящий под шаблон участок. Размеры шаблона и искомого фрагмента на изображении не совпадают (допустим приблизительно) -> результаты ни о чем. Разберитесь в принципе работы matchtemplate.

---

Если исходные данные поменять нельзя (размерность изображений не ваша ошибка), то это крутая задача по нахождению признака объекта на изображении, нахождении его примерных координат, свертки CNN и окончательного распознавания. Та еще задачка.

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо) Действительно проблема в размерах шаблона и оригинала. Должны быть одинаковыми объекты.
Я пробол делать ресайз как в примере https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/
Но похоже что то не так делал. Спасибо тебе дружище! Ты прекратил мои мучения) Как только поменял размеры, все заработало.